# "wanna" or "wanna" to?

Tags: differences, slang

Sometimes I hear "wanna do something," but other times I hear "wanna **to** do something." In the dictionary, I found that *wanna* means "want to."

Why do some people use "wanna to"?

Comment: I feel like you might have misheard _wanna do_ for _wanted to_.

Comment: Both expressions are found, esp. in speech.

Comment: Check out ell.stackexchange.com -- you will find more learner-level posts there.

Comment: Better asked on ell.stackexchange.com


Comment: I agree with @Simon ... quite often the 't' is dropped in *wanted to* and it gets pronounced *wanna to*. You didn't mishear it ... you just misinterpreted it.

Comment: @SimonKuang: You should post that as a full answer.

Comment: @vince It's an answer now.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asks for an opinion as to why people do something. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably (spoken/written) **informal** language. **Wanna** is a shorthand for **want + to** (except for third person singular). Why they like that? They just wanna to.

Comment: No native speaker of English would ever intend to say 'wanna to' as in 'I want to to ...'. So you would also not want to transcribe what you heard as 'wanna to' (even if it phonologically sounded like that.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like you might have misheard *wanna do* for *wanted to*, so ...

Comment: "I really wanna to drive you, crazy " http://www.metrolyrics.com/wanna-get-to-know-you-lyrics-gunit.html